# SublimeText2 CodeIntel Mac Issue

Tags: php, python, osx-lion, sublimetext2

I installed the Package Browser and install CodeIntel the autocomplete code but when I try to index my code in the console shows this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 356, in run_
  File "./SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 878, in run
  File "./SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 233, in guess_lang
  File "./SublimeCodeIntel.py", line 475, in codeintel_manager
  File "/Users/josedx20/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeCodeIntel/libs/codeintel2/manager.py", line 155, in upgrade
    self.db.upgrade()
  File "/Users/josedx20/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeCodeIntel/libs/codeintel2/database/database.py", line 516, in upgrade
    % curr_ver)
codeintel2.common.DatabaseError: cannot upgrade from db v2.0.24: no upgrader for this version
```

Any idea? im user MacOSX Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your copy of SublimeCodeIntel. In a terminal type:

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeCodeIntel
git pull
```

and restart your Sublime editor. The latest revision supports version 2.0.24.

Not sure how your database was upgraded with your SublimeCodeIntel copy being older; perhaps you ran a copy of the Komodo IDE? It uses codeintel too; in fact, this is where codeintel stems from.

Comment: macjose:SublimeCodeIntel josedx20$ git pull
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: i resolved! i use this comand:
git clone http://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel